# Selenium TestNG - Method from other class executes before completing execution of current class

Tags: selenium-webdriver, testng

Example:

```
Class 1{
@test(priority=1){
 }
@test(priority=2){
 }
}

Class 2{
@test(priority=1){
}
@test(priority=2){
}
}
```

When I execute these classes in test suite, first @test of class 1 executes and then a new browser instance opens in which first @test of class 2 executes. Now second @test of class 1 executes and then second @test of class 2 executes. **Note: Test parallel is false in this case.**
Need to know why this happens. I want execution of first class to complete before it starts with second. I could not figure out. I did some workaround nothing worked.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

TestNG is working as expected: You use `priority` and TestNG orders tests with it.

Check the documentation about [dependencies](http://testng.org/doc/documentation-main.html#dependent-methods) and you'll find what you are looking for.

I think you should use `dependsOnMethods` instead of `priority` (or maybe the `group-by-instances` feature).

Comment: Actually I have around 100 such classes with same kind of priorities in that  case, every class should get executed in the same way (like first test of class 1,  first test of class 2,  first test of class 3 and so on..) but here only first two classes executes simultaneously and then next two classes. Could you please explain.

Comment: Ok, in this case, could you share a project that shows the issue and open a new issue on https://github.com/cbeust/testng/issues/ with the project?

Comment: The idea is not to share your project, but to create a similar one (other names, empty test methods, ...) to be able to have something runnable and reproduce the issue easily.